# How do I change the value of a boolean variable inside an if statement in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

In this SwiftUI file, I am trying to set a @State variable to false in the if statement however I am getting an error.

Here is the code:

```
@State var showingTags: Bool = true
```

```
 if product_array_status_search {
                        
                        VStack(spacing: 15) {
//HERE: showingTags = false

                                ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
                                    ForEach(MarketplaceModel.filteredBusiness.filter { ($0.business_name ?? "").contains(searchText)}, id: \.self) { business in
                                        HStack {                                              
                                                    Image("ImageHere")
                                                        .resizable()
                                                                                            
                                            Text(business.business_name ?? "")
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        } else if product_array_status_tags {
                             ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
                                LazyVGrid(columns: Array(repeating: GridItem(.flexible(),spacing: 10), count: 2),spacing: 20){
                                    ForEach(MarketplaceModel.product_tag_array){product in
                                        ProductView(productData: product)

                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        } else {
                             SearchPlaceholderView()
                        }
```

When I put in the line 'showingTags = false', I get the error: Type '()' cannot conform to 'View' (on the if statement)

I have also tried making a function that does this and calling that but I get the same error.

How can I make showingTags = false when this if statement is initialised?

Comment: it makes no sense to change a `@State` from within the function that can be called many times whenever apple needs to redraw this view. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: In the SwiftUI any code have to run inside an event: Like onAppear, onDisappear, onTapGesture, etc. if you want a change in the State as soon as the view Appears use the ViewModifier .onAppear { showingTags.toggle() }... but your code is incomplete, try to show the complete code or a Proof of Concept if the view itself is too complicated. Ie. where "product_array_status_search" comes from? BTW, not recommended style for Swift.